# What does this lemma mean?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> **Lemma**: Suppose that $f \colon [a,b] \rightarrow \Bbb R$ is continuous and $\lambda \in \Bbb R$. If $f(w) > \lambda$ for some $w \in [a,b]$, then there exists $\delta \in \Bbb R^+$ such that $f(x) > \lambda$ whenever $x \in [a,b]$ and $| x-w| < \delta$.

What does this lemma mean? From intuition my feelings on this are that it means if we have a region of the graph that is $> \lambda$ then there is region greater than and less than $\delta$ where for all $x$ in that region $f(x) > \lambda$ Is that correct?

Comment: Almost. It means that if you have a point $ w \in [a,b] $ such that $ f(w) > \lambda $ then there exists a small area (i.e. small $ \delta$) such that $ f(x) > \lambda $ for all $ x \in [w - \delta, w + \delta] $

Comment: I see, that makes sense thank you! How would I go about proving it?

Comment: It means that if $f$ is strictly greater than $\lambda$ when evaluated at some point, then it remains strictly greater than $\lambda$ when evaluated at points close enough to the initial point.

Comment: @dafinguzman When you say at points close enough to the initial point. Do you mean $x \in [w - \delta, w + \delta]$?

Comment: Hint: let $d = f(w)-\lambda$ be the distance from $f(w)$ to $\lambda$. Then you need a neighborhood of $w$ in the domain that will get you closer to $f(w)$ than that distance. Can you find one according to the definition of continuity at $w$?

Comment: @PeakingFriendly suppose otherwise and prove that $ f(x) $ is discontinuous

Comment: Yes, close enough means "closer than some $\delta$". You need to prove that $\delta$ exists. Luckily there is an "exists" somewhere in the definition of continuity.

Comment: So can we say that because $f(x)$ is continuous, we can pick an appropriate $\delta$ to make the  $\epsilon$ inequality hold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My feeling is that $\epsilon$'s drive beginning analysis students crazy. None of them have come into the classroom armed yet and all seem to survive in time, but there is a mean and confused look for the first few weeks of proving anything about limits and continuity using $\epsilon$'s.

Consider the following two definitions of continuity at a point.

> **Definition** 1.  A function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is *continuous* at a
>   point $w$ if, for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ so that
>   $$f(w)-\epsilon < f(x) < f(w)+\epsilon$$ whenever $x$ is a point of
>   the interval for which $|x-w|<\delta$.

and

> **Definition** 2.  A function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is *continuous* at a point $w$ if, for any numbers $\lambda_1< f(w) < \lambda_2$ there
>   is a $\delta>0$ so that $$\lambda_1 < f(x) <  \lambda_2.$$
>   whenever $x$ is a point of the interval for which $|x-w|<\delta$.

These two statements are utterly and completely and trivially equivalent.  You don't have to insist that this number $\lambda_1<f(w)$ is given by $f(w)-\epsilon$
or that  $\lambda_2$ must have to be $f(w)+\epsilon$.  Just anything smaller than $f(w)$ and anything bigger.  To get used to this try reproving some of your simpler exercises without ever  using an $\epsilon$ (or anything "small").  Throw away $\epsilon$'s for a  week  and see if you survive.

Answer (score 0):

$A$= $f^{-1}(]\lambda, f(w)+\epsilon[)$ must be open by continuity of $f$ and contains $w$; take$]w-\epsilon,w+\epsilon[\subset A$ so you have $f(]w-\epsilon,w+\epsilon[)\subset\space]\lambda, f(w)+\epsilon[$.